# how rename script make?

Tags: bash, scripts, rename

we need script to rename.
is anybody know it?
please help us.

rename1 before

```
abc/a.ext, b.ext, c.ext, ..
```

after

```
abc/01+abc.ext 02+abc.ext 03+abc.ext ..
```

this is rename `number+current directory name`
but extension is not one type.
we use file some extension.
txt,jpg,png,raw,etc ..

rename2
before

```
abc/10+file1.ext, 4+file2.ext, 5+file3.ext, ..
```

after

```
abc/01+file1.ext 02+file2.ext, 03+file3.ext, ..
```

yes, this is rename `change number only`
number sort is date time.

we use rename application metamorphose2 now.
but metamorphose2 is can't save config file.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks for welcome.
but our question unclear? sorry.
terminal use okay, but we want autorename action.
action menu=context menu with dolphine file manager.
sorry but we troublesome so we do not want to enter that command, place or rename destination every time.
that is get tired.

Comment: @steeldriver thank you. we didn't know that.

Comment: this is have no answer.